# Increase ratio pre test and post test

Tags: descriptive-statistics, pre-post-comparison

I have a pre test and post test and for each question (15 questions in total) students get 1,2 or zero points. There is an increase in post test but I want to know which score value increased more than others. For instance, I hypothesize that score 0 is increased to one rather than score 1 increase to 2. I have 15 questions in both test and so 15 different variables with values of 0, 1 and 2. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not simply code the shifts as a categorical variable? For example `0->1 = "1"`, `1->2 = "2"`, `0->2 = "3"`, etc. Then perform chi-square test of equality of all the proportions.

Comment: Seems reasonable, how can i do it in spss? Recode? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Yes, recode, "into new variables", then go to Chi-square in Nonparametric tests.